# How to extract information from firestore & functions return from a firestore update trigger?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get some information from the update of a firestore file through functions.

I've already managed to get the firestore trigger right (functions is working when my firestore file is updated), but I cannot get the information that was updated through functions.

Here is my functions code:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
//const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.enviaMensagem = functions.firestore
  .document("Events/{eventID}/Listas/Convidados")
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    const eventID = context.params.eventID;
    console.log("eventID: ", eventID);
    if (change.after.data()) {
        const data = change.after.data();

        if ( data!.reference) {
            console.log(data!.reference);
        } else {
            console.log('not possible to get the user reference');
        }

        console.log(data!.toString());
        console.log(change.after.toString());

    }
  });
```

[**SOLVED**] My **problem number 1** is when I try `console.log(data!.toString());` the return to the console becames `[object Object]` and not the actual data.

[**SOLVED**] My **problem number 2** is that I cannot get the info that has been inserted to the firestore file.

this is the structure of the info that has been inserted to the firestore file:
[updated data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrLdN.png)

the structure is:
{[**reference key**]:{apelido:'abc', estado:'def', **referencia:[reference key]**}}

I need to retrive the reference key, which is the primary tag for this map, and also inside the structure by the tag "referencia"

How can I retrive this reference key so I can use it?

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**
Here is the print of my logged object: [Logged object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfmZH.png)
I need to retrive this long string that appears on top and botton of the log "bJaETeYN4hYJqRN9PnmWfrhs7eC2"
This string is different for every user and I need the info of which user is doing the action.

**UPDATE 2**
I've managed to get what I need with the function `Object.keys(data!)[0]`
I'm leaving the solution here so other can use it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to log an object with JavaScript, don't call toString() on it.  Just pass it directly:

```
console.log(data!)
```

The document you've written is a little bit awkward.  For some reason, it contains a single field whose name is "bJaE...7eC2".  Since you didn't show the code that writes this data, we can't really tell why this is, or if it's just a mistake.

If you need to work with the document exactly as written, you're going to have to refer to the referencia field through the oddly-named field it's in:

```
console.log(data!.bJaE...7eC2.referencia)
```

You will have to replace "bJaE...7eC2" with the full string you see in the document field.

But that field name is probably a mistake, and you should go back and fix your client code to do what you actually want.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've managed to get my object on logged correctly now.

Comment: OK, if you found this answer helpful, please upvote and mark it as correct, which is conventional for Stack Overflow and helps others know the information is correct.

Comment: I've updated the post with my logged object so it can be easier for you to understand what I need now. 
The object structure is correct. This long string is the user reference on my database and that is exactly the information that I need. How can I get this info?

Comment: You will have to examine the contents of the document using the data provided in the snapshot.